# 2 ISP's, 2 Modems & 1 Network

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, router, windows-8.1

I have a DSL ISP that goes through a combo modem/wireless router (AT&T NVG510) upstairs (which is required to send a signal to my wireless devices). I have broadband ISP cable with modem (Surfboard SB6121) in the basement which, of course, is sent to a router (Linksys WRT 1900AC) then through a switch which in turn operates my basement network and wireless devices. All of my computers are running Windows 8.1.

I would like to get the upstairs computer on the downstairs network at the same time continue having both ISP’s and if I have one of the ISP’s fail it will automatically switch everything over to the one that is operating

Is all I am asking at all possible and what will I have to purchase (if anything) to make this happen? I’m sure you can determine that the way I am asking this question I am not very computer savvy (don’t know technical terms); and will be glad to answer questions to clarify.

If you can reply/answer please be very specific and provide step-by-step instructions if this is possible and I appreciate your taking time to read this.

Comment: A dual WAN network is certainly possible, but it even close to be trivial or easy if you want automatic failover.

Comment: That means nothing to me but thanks for the reply.

Comment: Don't understand--- I DID say something.

Comment: Let me try again.  DUAL WAN is possible.  AUTOMATIC FAILOVER makes this very HARD, or expensive.

Comment: What is your example of  'Expensive'?

Answer (score 0):

Merge the networks:

- Setup router one on subnet 192.168.x.0 and router two on 192.168.y.0 so they dont conflic
- Run ethernet between the two, or homeplugs if you like

Failover:

- Buy an LB router, they start from €200
- Bridge your DSL Router/Modem
- Connect Cable modem and DSL modem to LB router.
- Connect linksys to LB and use it for wireless access (AP mode)

You'll probably need another wifi unit, or buy a DSL modem so you dont need to bridge the current one.